# Is it possible to inherit all operators in C++?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, operators

One can inherit all constructors of a base class using following code:

```cpp
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
public:
    using BaseClass::BaseClass;
    ...
};
```

Is it possible to inherit all operators in simillar way (one line)?

Paticular code that does not compile:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <memory>

using std::string;

struct A : string
{
    using string::string;
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<string> str;
    *str = 'a';

    std::shared_ptr<A> a;
    *a = 'a'; // err: E0349 no operator "=" matches these operands

}
```

If I write class like this, then the code above compiles and runs:

```cpp
struct A : string
{
    using string::string;
    using string::operator=;
};
```

Comment: There's no need, since the base class is `public` you inherit everything automatically.

Comment: I added a code example. Could you please check it?

Comment: Don't inherit from classes in `std` namespace, they are not designed for that.

Comment: @lorro so do I need to implement my own string class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All member functions, that includes operator overloads, are inheritted following the regular inheritance rules for member functions.

Like @sklott mentioned, you need to implicitly pull in functions from the base class if they are shadowed in the derived (as in same name, but different arguments, etc).

In your case, the default assignment operator of `A` shadows the assignment operators of `string`. Therefore those must be explicitly injected via `using`.

Comment: I added a code example. Could you please check it?

Comment: Not exactly. If you "shadow" function by defining function with existing name, but different arguments. Then you also need to "pull" base class functions if you want to use them.

Comment: @sklott Yes, you are correct. I didn't think of that case.

Comment: I do not think it is my case.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly your case. Auto generated assignment operator overrides `operator =(char c)`. So you need `using string::operator =;` for it to work. All other operators are not "shadowed", you can check. PS: Even if you delete auto generated assignment operators it didn't help.

Comment: @sklott that's an important enough point to be turned into an answer, not a comment.  But I believe I've seen this case come up a long time ago, so it's probably a duplicate.

Comment: @DeiDei `std::string` is a `typedef` for `std::basic_string<>`, which is a template class. ADL does not include base template classes.

Comment: @DeiDei could you please add sklott's explanation to the answer, so I can mark it as correct one?